# error LNK2005: "already defined in SkinHeaderCtrl.obj"

Tags: c++, lnk2005

I am Getting this error "Error  2   error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall CMemDC::~CMemDC(void)" (??1CMemDC@@UAE@XZ) already defined in SkinHeaderCtrl.obj C:\Users\anthonyd\Desktop\ASPX\STP\nafxcwd.lib(afxglobals.obj)  STP
"

I have read through many similar questions but can not find what fits. Could someone help please?

```
   // SkinHeaderCtrl.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "STP.h"
#include "SkinHeaderCtrl.h"
#include "memdc.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

#define BACKGROUND RGB(218,218,218)// was 218,218,218
#define HEIGHT 16
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CSkinHeaderCtrl

CSkinHeaderCtrl::CSkinHeaderCtrl()
{
}

CSkinHeaderCtrl::~CSkinHeaderCtrl()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSkinHeaderCtrl, CHeaderCtrl)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CSkinHeaderCtrl)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CSkinHeaderCtrl message handlers

void CSkinHeaderCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{

}

void CSkinHeaderCtrl::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    CRect rect, rectItem, clientRect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    GetClientRect(&clientRect);
    CMemDC memDC(&dc, rect);
    CDC bitmapDC;
    bitmapDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

//  memDC.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(76,85,118));
    memDC.FillSolidRect(&rect, BACKGROUND);

    CBitmap bitmapSpan;
    bitmapSpan.LoadBitmap(IDB_COLUMNHEADER_SPAN);
    CBitmap* pOldBitmapSpan = bitmapDC.SelectObject(&bitmapSpan);

//  memDC.StretchBlt(rect.left+2, 0, rect.Width(), 12, &bitmapDC, 0, 0, 1, 12, SRCCOPY);
    memDC.StretchBlt(rect.left+2, 0, rect.Width(), HEIGHT, &bitmapDC, 0, 0, 1, 12, SRCCOPY);

    bitmapDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmapSpan);
    bitmapSpan.DeleteObject();

    int nItems = GetItemCount();

    CBitmap bitmap;
    CBitmap bitmap2;
    CBitmap bitmap3;
```

Here is the skinheaderctrl.h

```
#if !defined(AFX_SKINHEADERCTRL_H__8B0847B1_B4E6_4372_A62D_038582FFEA5C__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_SKINHEADERCTRL_H__8B0847B1_B4E6_4372_A62D_038582FFEA5C__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// SkinHeaderCtrl.h : header file
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CSkinHeaderCtrl window

class CSkinHeaderCtrl : public CHeaderCtrl
{
// Construction
public:
    CSkinHeaderCtrl();

// Attributes
public:

// Operations
public:

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CSkinHeaderCtrl)
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
public:
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
    virtual ~CSkinHeaderCtrl();

    // Generated message map functions
protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(CSkinHeaderCtrl)
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
    //}}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_SKINHEADERCTRL_H__8B0847B1_B4E6_4372_A62D_038582FFEA5C__INCLUDED_)
```

***Update***

On the skinheaderctrl.cpp I have a includes #include "memdc.h" do I want to update this to CMemDC?

Comment: Did you define the destructor in the header file perhaps?

Comment: What's this `"memdc.h"`? Is it defining *another* CMemDC class?

Comment: @NathanOliver I added the header above. I'm better with c+ and not c++

Comment: @BoPersson when I comment out that file I get a lot of errors with "Error C2065: 'CMemDC' : undeclared identifier"

Comment: What is the C+ language?

Comment: The source looks really old (`_MSC_VER > 1000` and the odd include guards), like VC6 or worse. What version of the compiler do you use now?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews c++ , I didnt write this I'm just updating it.

Comment: @BoPersson I will need to look. I am not the original programmer for this. Yes it was written a long time ago!

Answer (score 2):

`CMemDC` is an internal helper class in MFC (see [Internal Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc714512%28v=vs.115%29)).  You've apparently defined your own `CMemDC` class, with the result that the linker is seeing two destructors with the same name.  You'll either have to rename your class to something else or put it in a namespace to avoid the conflict.

Comment: I did not see where the class CMemDC is called or included/linked. I do show a header MEMDC.H with class of CMemDC. This should be right?